# vs compiler complaining about missing reference in project.json but .net proj is not core

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have an MVC app which targets .NET f/w 4.5.2. I was copying over some files from a .NET core app on a previous branch. I installed a few npm packages on the previous branch. Now on my new clean branch which I just created from develop, VS is returning the following error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Your project is not referencing the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" framework. Add a reference to ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" in the "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore.    MyCompany.Website

I think project.json is a file specific to the .NET Core f/w so the compiler shouldn't be requiring a project.json update in a 4.5.2 app. What do I need to do to get around this error message?  I tried "git clean -f" on this directory but the error still occurs.  Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in another thread.  Look for a project.lock.json file then delete it.  Issue fixed.

Comment: Then mark this as duplicate. At the very least, add a linkg to that other question

Comment: wasn't a duplicate. it just touched on the solution.

Comment: Add the link anyway. Answers that say "just delete this" aren't very good - how can one be sure this won't break anything?

Comment: b/c a core file is not valid in .net 4.5.2 and in this case it breaks it

Comment: That's wrong. If it was invalid, it wouldn't be picked up. You *can* use `project.json` outside .NET Core to handle transitive dependencies. Deleting the files is one solution. *Fixing* them so you can keep your nuget dependencies clean is a better one.

Comment: Anyway, post the link. Otherwise this answer won't be useful to anyone else with the same problem.

Comment: Mine said assets.project.json

Answer (score 4):

It's kind of a bug in Visual Studio.

See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/20628

A solution is to look for obsolete `project.lock.json` and/or `project.assets.json` files and delete them.